# Intent.ACTION_CALL force close

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to make a phone call but I get a force close:

```
private Uri phonenumbers(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
     if (groupPosition == 1 && childPosition == 1) return Uri.parse("tel:15555555555");
     return null;
}

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View View) {
        Uri uri = phonenumbers(groupPosition, childPosition);                 
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NEVERMIND. I was hitting the wrong child.  I keep forgetting the first group/child is 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String number = "tel:+919966626261";

 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number)); 
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

In manifest add this permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

or

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"></uses-permission>
```